# Ajax making parts of jquery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When I use the ajax code on the same page or external .js page it doesn't work and makes other parts of the code (jquery) not work. The ajax must work on .kb li click

When in use it affects (worked before ajax was added):

- Back button isn't being prepended
- Back button (.kb-sub li:first-child) doesn't go back anymore

Same thing happens if I put the ajax request in another click(function) or on another page and not in the included external page

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.kb li').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).data('parent');

        $('.kb').fadeOut();
        $('.kb-sub').delay(400).fadeIn();

        $(".kb-sub li:contains('Back')").remove();
        $('.kb-sub').prepend('<li>Back</li>');

        $('.kb-sub li:first-child').click(function() {
            $('.kb-sub').fadeOut();
            $('.kb').delay(400).fadeIn();
        });

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"data.php",
            data:"parent="+parent,
            success:function(result){
                $(".kb-sub").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing exactly what it should do, the reason it seems as if it's not working is because you `prepend` the *back* `li`, and then you replace all the html inside the `.kb-sub` elements with the result of the ajax request with `$(".kb-sub").html(result);`, erasing what you just "prepended".

To fix this I would suggest moving the code up top inside the success handler of the ajax call something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.kb li').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).data('parent');

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"data.php",
            data:"parent="+parent,
            success:function(result){
                $(".kb-sub").html(result);


                $('.kb').fadeOut();
                $('.kb-sub').delay(400).fadeIn();

                $(".kb-sub li:contains('Back')").remove();
                $('.kb-sub').prepend('<li>Back</li>');

                $('.kb-sub li:first-child').click(function() {
                    $('.kb-sub').fadeOut();
                    $('.kb').delay(400).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```